# How to correctly pass header parameter in Angular?

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-core-webapi

Having some issues passing my header parameter in Angular. The error I'm getting coming from my API is "Session Id is required" as indicated below. 
Here is my endpoint:

```
       [HttpDelete("")]

        public IActionResult EndSession(
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Session Id is required.")]
            [StringLength(maximumLength: 36, MinimumLength = 36, ErrorMessage  = "Session Id should be 36 characters long.")]
            [FromHeader] string sessionId)
```

Here is my service method in the angular application:

```
public async EndSession(sessionId: string): Promise<boolean> {

const headers = new HttpHeaders()
  .set(sessionId , 'string')

this.appSettings = (await this.configService.loadConfig().toPromise());

return this.http.delete<boolean>(this.appSettings.apiSetting.apiAddress + this.apiRoute, { headers })
  .pipe(
    retry(1),
    catchError(this.handleError)
)
  .toPromise()
```

In the component that I call this method I have the sessionId hard coded as follows:

```
  export class AppBarHorizontalComponent implements OnInit {
  sessionId = "4CB3C85B-2C11-48AE-8D51-1DC30242A743"
  constructor(private oauthService: OAuthService, private userService: UserSessionService) {  }

public logout(): void {
this.userService.EndSession(this.sessionId);
//this.oauthService.logOut(false);
```

What I expect to happen that the sessionId is passed as a header parameter correctly so the api method can execute as normal.

Comment: Hi please check this: https://therichpost.com/angular-9-http-request-with-body-and-headers/

Answer (score 0):

Found my mistake. In my service method while setting the headers I mixed up the parameters. It was:

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders()
  .set(sessionId , 'string')
```

Changed to:

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders()
  .set('sessionId', sessionId)
```